# using an if statement inside of a map function, but 'this is not binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, scope

I get a "Cannot read property 'filter_selected' of undefined" error.
I tried binding the cards in constructor. And tried it without binding.

The console.log of 'this'  inside the map function returns App, but there is no state property inside of the object returned.

I also tried changing the if statements to ternary operations, but to no avail.

I think it is a scope issue, but can't figure it out.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    filteredphotoArray: [],
    filter_selected: "all"
  };
  this.cards = this.cards.bind(this);
}

cards = data.map((card, i, imgArr) => {
  console.log(this); //App, but no state property in App
  if (this.state.filter_selected === "all") {
    return data;
  } else if (card.filter === this.state.filter_selected) {
    return card;
  } 
});
```

Comment: Your `class` is missing a `}` in this question.

Comment: Actually, the render method is missing as well. But all other parts are working fine. Just can't refer to this inside the if statement. I didn't add the other parts.

Comment: what is the value `data` in this example?

Comment: in you're constructor you're doing `this.cards.bind(this)` as though `this.cards` is a function. But the only code you've shown us where you create `this.cards` is the result of a map statement, so it must be an array, not a function. Did you perhaps mean to wrap that data.map call inside a function?

Comment: data is a json object.  Nicholas, thanks I missed that.  I'll try wrapping it in a function.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `data.map` callback runs before the class constructor. Since the `state` is defined inside the constructor, the `data.map` callback gives an error that the `state` is undefined. Also, the `cards` is a variable, not a function, therefore there is no need of binding it in `constructor`.

To solve this problem, you can initialize the `cards` variable inside constructor like this

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filteredphotoArray: [],
      filter_selected: "all"
    };
    // Just make sure that the "data" variable is accessible here.
    this.cards = data.map((card, i, imgArr) => {
     if (this.state.filter_selected === "all") {
       return data;
     } else if (card.filter === this.state.filter_selected) {
       return card;
     } 
  });
}
```

The other way can be to make it a function and call the function where it is needed like

```
 cards = () => {
   return data.map((card, i, imgArr) => {
     if (this.state.filter_selected === "all") {
       return data;
     } else if (card.filter === this.state.filter_selected) {
       return card;
     } 
  });
 }

render(){
   let card = this.cards();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cards = data.map((card, i, imgArr) => {
  console.log(this); //App, but no state property in App
  if (this.state.filter_selected === "all") {
    return data;
  } else if (card.filter === this.state.filter_selected) {
    return card;
  } 
});
```

This syntax is using ES7 property initializers, and is being executed immediately in the constructor of your object. Notably, the transpiler will put this *before* the lines where you initialize this.state, and so this.state is not available. You can see the [transpiled version here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECCAO9oFMAeAXZA7AJjAwgPYC28hW260A3gFDTTDkToBOArsOoawBTytC8CAEoa9aBHbxkfAUNEBuCegAWASwgA6FmEzQAvOIYMAZupCZWyHPFWFusVqzABPAFzQA2gF0ANBJmFlYA-hDIIMhcNp4ARGAgILESAL7KDGqaWsBgrHiG0JnaOXnaAEbquLxFIsoptLQl-UY4emBaxGDwvLxNftDq_erEAOZOrGIGAHzGjMyEkVoghCPVGkrQAPSbCPD9ZexUWISS6HrI0PIyrOiuA1hwiBLqptBrWbqYWuaWsmERUUwOEMBiM8USsTEdBM0Gs6HYrAerTO6WgKRQIHCA1evVyOG-wVkIKMRR0Zy-P1C4Ui0RwUMCsOQ8MRjDxqPRtBStU5QA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0). It's a bit messy, but just notice that the `_this.cards =` part happens before the `_this.state =` part

If you truely want it to execute in the constructor but want it to execute after the state has been created, then you can either manually put it in the constructor after the state, or use a property initializer for the state as well, as in:

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
      filteredphotoArray: [],
      filter_selected: "all"
    }

    cards = data.map((card, i, imgArr) => {
     if (this.state.filter_selected === "all") {
       return data;
     } else if (card.filter === this.state.filter_selected) {
       return card;
     } 
  });
}
```

However, i think you meant for this to be a function, in which case there isn't a need for that much of a change. Just wrap it in a function. It will still be defined up front, but it won't be executed until later.

```
cards = () => data.map((card, i, imgArr) => {
  console.log(this); //App, but no state property in App
  if (this.state.filter_selected === "all") {
    return data;
  } else if (card.filter === this.state.filter_selected) {
    return card;
  } 
})
```